# Почему увеличивается объем задействованной памяти

Tags: java, java-8

Решил посмотреть какие задачи даются на собеседовании в Яндекс. Наткнулся на такое задание, алгоритмическая часть которого не вызвала вопросов, однако не проходит тест по памяти. Так вот вопрос заключается в следующем: по какой причине задействованная память тут может увеличиваться, если количество переменных константно и не зависит от объема входных данных? И как это можно было бы исправить?
P.S. Еще пробовал просто со сканнером, но ошибка та же, только валится на 189 тесте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int n = readInt(bf);
        if (n == 0) return;
        int prevN = readInt(bf);
        bw.write(prevN + "\n");
        bw.flush();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            int x = readInt(bf);
            if (x != prevN) {
                bw.write(x + "\n");
                bw.flush();
                prevN = x;
            }
        }
        bf.close();
    }
    
    static int readInt(BufferedReader bf) throws IOException {
        int number = 0;
        boolean dig = false;
        boolean minus = false;
        for (int c = 0; (c = bf.read()) != -1; ) {
            if (c == '-') {
                c = bf.read();
                minus = true;
            }
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                dig = true;
                number = number * 10 + c - '0';
            } else if (dig) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (minus) {
            return -number;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень странно. Как будто Ваше решение совершенно правильное. А как попробовать закинуть в решающую систему своё решение? Хочу попообовать сделать то же самое на С++

Comment: @S.H.: Можете перейти в сам контест и выбрать 3 задание https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/8458/enter/

Comment: `x + "\n"` - создает новые объекты в куче. Они живут недолго и не должны влиять на память, но они точно ведут к тому, что будет постоянно происходить сборка мусора (и это будет точно влиять на время работы программы). Замените на два отдельных `write`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Спасибо, учту это!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чет у вас сильно сложно. Нет никакого смысла вообще строки в числа переводить. Там же уже все упорядоченно, вам надо только убрать дубликаты, а дубликаты числа являются также дублткатами в стоковом виде.

Вот пример (сам не проверял)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

    int lines = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());
    String currentLine = null;

    for(int i=0; i<lines; i++)
    {
        String next = bf.readLine();
        if (currentLine == null || !currentLine.equals(next))
        {
            currentLine = next;
            bw.write(currentLine);
            bw.write('\n');
        }
    }

    bf.close();
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, что такое решение лучше, не подумал, однако и оно по какой то причине не проходит по памяти, тоже падает на 193 тесте

Comment: Попробуйте убрать буфер при чтении и записи, может в нем дело.

Comment: Ваше решение прошло для Java 7 (16 мб), спасибо. Правда все же все равно непонятно откуда столько памяти

Comment: Видимо, сама виртуальная машина какую то помять занимает.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понимаю...

У меня была похожая задача, нужно было придумать код который будет принимать числа и сохранять в переменную только максимально заданное число. А после ввода 0 или отрицательного числа выдавать результат максимально введенного числа и завершать программу.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class Executeble {
public static void main(String args[]) {
short ip;
Scanner kb = new Scanner(in);
out.println("введите число.");
ip = kb.nextShort();
short lip = ip;
System.out.println("Num " +ip);
while (ip > 0) {
if (ip < lip) {
    System.out.println("Num " +ip);
    }
if (ip > lip) {
    lip = ip; 
    System.out.println("Num " +ip);
    ip = kb.nextShort();
}  else {
    ip = kb.nextShort() ;
}
}
kb.close();
out.println("Max Value - " +lip+ ".");
}}
```

вы можете изменить условие на отображение и получать результат только в тех случаях когда число хранящее в переменной меньше введенного числа. А  именно... вот код:

```
    System.out.println("введите число.");
    }
if (ip > lip) {
    lip = ip; 
    System.out.println("Num " +ip);
    ip = kb.nextShort();
}  else {
    ip = kb.nextShort() ;
}
}
kb.close();
}}
```

Comment: import static java.lang.System.*; на данный не использующийся  импорт не обращайте внимания... Я создал данный код с перспективой модификации если появятся еще идеи...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но боюсь это не  то, что в данном случае подходит